# Why do we add s and are in these sentences?

Tags: verb-forms

My question is why do we add *s* to these sentences:

1. > Are you the one who plays the violin?

why do we add *s* to *play*  and does *one* in this sentence mean *you*?

2. > You are the one who is funny in the class.

My second  question is why do we put *is* instead of *are* and do we by *one* mean *you*?

I am looking forward to the answer and I appreciate your effort.

Comment: Because the number of the verb agrees with "the one".  *You* is being identified as this other person (the one) that people are speaking of, or as the individual with a specific quality (the funny one).

Comment: Replace "the one who" by "the person who, then you see that "one" does not mean "you".

Answer (score 1):

> Are you the one who plays the violin?

Here we put "s" in "play" because *one* that refers to *you* is singular. If the sentence happens to be

> Are you the **ones** who *play* the violin?

We use "play" because "ones" that refers to *you* is plural

More example of this:

- He/She/It drives
- They drive
- We drive
- You drive
- He/She/It cooks
- They cook
- We cook
- You cook

> You are the one who is funny in the class.

Because it is definite that *you* is singular because you used "one". If you used "ones" instead of "one" then it becomes *You are the ones who are funny in class*

Answer (score 0):

"One" is often used as a sort of pronoun that can refer to an indefinite, hypothetical person. Presumably, before the student said "You are the one who is funny in the class," another student had said that they're a funny person or a class clown. The student who spoke the sentence disagrees, so "the person who is funny" must be someone else. "One" in this context means simply "person."